# How to optimise a sqlite_3 query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My existing sql query with conditional data fetch from various tables is very slow, need to understand how to optimize query.

Existing query is trying to get material information from 'Material' table with some conditions. If there is 'printer' in 'Config' table return only info of 'materials' in 'Config' table. If there is no 'printer' in 'Config' table return info of all materials from 'Available material' table. This is handled using case and left joins. But required expressions are repeated in 'joins' as well as in the 'where' clause. So required a way to store 'result' of some sub query and reuse it later. I have sqlite query which looks like this:-

```
select m.name from material m 

left join available_material_printmode_config ac on ac.material_name = m.name and
(SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM available_material_printmode_config 
WHERE printer_name ='123' LIMIT 1)) and 
(SELECT case when material_name is null then 0 else 1 end 
FROM available_material_printmode_config WHERE printer_name ='123' 
and printmode_name = '2' LIMIT 1)

left join available_materials am1 on am1.material_name = m.name 
and ((SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM available_material_printmode_config 
WHERE printer_name ='123' LIMIT 1)) !=1 
or ((SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM available_material_printmode_config 
WHERE printer_name ='123' LIMIT 1)) 
and (SELECT case when material_name is null then 1 else 0 end 
FROM available_material_printmode_config WHERE printer_name ='123' 
and printmode_name = '2' LIMIT 1)))

where
case
when 'true' == (select case when exists 
(select distinct 1 from available_material_printmode_config where printer_name = '123') 
THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) 
and (SELECT case when material_name is null then 0 else 1 end 
FROM available_material_printmode_config WHERE printer_name ='123' 
and printmode_name = '2' LIMIT 1)
then
ac.printer_name = '123' and ac.printmode_name = '2'
else
am1.printer_name = '123'
end
```

Wanted to know if there is any way to reuse result of below mentioned sqls as they are repeated:

```
(SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM available_material_printmode_config 
WHERE printer_name ='123' LIMIT 1))
```

and

```
(SELECT case when material_name is null then 0 else 1 end 
FROM available_material_printmode_config 
WHERE printer_name ='123' and printmode_name = '2' LIMIT 1)
```

**Alternatively I came up with something like this :-**

```
with 
printercheck as (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM available_material_printmode_config 
WHERE printer_name ='123' LIMIT 1) as p),
materialcheck as (SELECT case when material_name is null  then 0 else 1 end as m 
FROM available_material_printmode_config WHERE printer_name ='123' 
and printmode_name = '2' LIMIT 1)

select m.name from material m 

left join available_material_printmode_config ac on ac.material_name = m.name 
and (select p from printercheck limit 1) 
and (select m from materialcheck limit 1)

left join available_materials am1 on am1.material_name = m.name 
and ((select p from printercheck limit 1) != 1 
or ((select p from printercheck limit 1) 
and (select m from materialcheck limit 1) !=1 ))

where
case
when (select p from printercheck limit 1) and (select m from materialcheck limit 1)
then
ac.printer_name = '123' and ac.printmode_name = '2'
else
am1.printer_name = '123'
end
```

**This is the final query I am using now: inspired from accepted answer**

```
select m.name, m.color from material m inner join
available_material_printmode_config ac on ac.material_name is not null 
and m.name=ac.material_name    
where ac.printmode_name='2' and ac.printer_name='123' 
UNION 
select m.name,m.color from material m
inner join available_materials am on m.name=am.material_name 
where (not exists (select distinct 1 from available_material_printmode_config 
where printer_name = am.printer_name limit 1) 
or exists (select 1 from available_material_printmode_config 
where printer_name = am.printer_name and printmode_name = '2' 
and material_name is null LIMIT 1)) and am.printer_name='123';
```

My original query had 28 steps, aleternative one had 20 steps and final query has 9 steps. Steps are basically count I get using **explain query plan** sql command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a union query of your two sets. While no data or schema is posted, below may need adjustment. Also, subqueries are now correlated to outer query rows:

```
SELECT m.name 
FROM material m 
LEFT JOIN available_material_printmode_config ac 
  ON ac.material_name = m.name 
WHERE EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM available_material_printmode_config sub         
    WHERE ac.printer_name = sub.printer_name 
      AND ac.printmode_name = sub.print mode_name)
AND ac.printer_name = '123' AND ac.printmode_name = '2'

UNION

SELECT m.name
FROM material m 
LEFT JOIN available_materials am
  ON am.material_name = m.name 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM available_material_printmode_config sub
    WHERE am.printer_name = sub.printer_name 
      AND sub.printmode_name = '2')
AND am.printer_name = '123'
```

Comment: (SELECT 1 FROM available_material_printmode_config sub
    WHERE am.printer_name = sub.printer_name 
      AND sub.printmode_name = '2') this has to be repeated ?

Comment: Even with edit, your `EXISTS` subqueries does not correlate with outer query, so it checks against entire table not one row at a time. Please check against data to see if SQL works.

Comment: ok thanks, do not need subquery to be evaluated for each row.

Comment: I guess **WITH** stmts is just block name and will be executed for each row every time. i get the point now. but whole objective of this question is that **EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM available_material_printmode_config sub         
    WHERE ac.printer_name = sub.printer_name 
      AND ac.printmode_name = sub.print mode_name)** should not be executed everytime for each row. The answer you posted the above condition will be executed for each row and for both union sets.